# How do I add custom fonts in swiftui?

Tags: swiftui, custom-font

I want to add custom fonts to my swift ui game. Does anyone know how to do that? I tried watching a youtube video but i couldn’t find any good ones.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI won't display custom font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58864731/swiftui-wont-display-custom-font)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add custom font to your project and register it in `.plist`
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app

Then define

```
extension Font {
    struct Event {
        let name = Font.custom("GillSans-UltraBold", size: 14)
        let location = Font.custom("GillSans-SemiBold", size: 10)
        let date = Font.custom("GillSans-UltraBold", size: 16)
        let price = Font.custom("GillSans-SemiBoldItalic", size: 12)
    }
    static let event = Event()
}
```

Example usage:

```
Text("iPhone 12 Pro Super Max").font(Font.event.name)
```