# Where is Info.plist in Xcode 13? (missing, not inside project navigator)

Tags: xcode, xcode13, info-plist

Has anyone figured out how to add/edit values in the `Info.plist` of Xcode 13 yet? I see they moved the `Info.plist` from the navigator pane... but although I can find it, I'm not sure how to edit it.

Answer (score 200, accepted):

### It's a "feature."

You don't need it anymore. From the [Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-13-beta-release-notes):

> Projects created from several templates **no longer require configuration files such as entitlements and Info.plist files**. Configure common fields in the target’s Info tab, and build settings in the project editor. These files are added to the project when additional fields are used. (68254857)

So, instead of inside `Info.plist`, edit properties like `NSCameraUsageDescription` here:

```
Project -> Targets -> Info -> Custom iOS Target Properties
```

[image: Options similar to those previously found in Info.plist]

The first time you add/edit, Xcode will automatically generate a new `Info.plist` file that’s kind of synced<sup>**1**</sup> with `Custom iOS Target Properties`. Xcode will later merge them for you.

<sup>**[1]**: They’re not fully synced. Some properties like `NSCameraUsageDescription` will only appear in Custom iOS Target Properties, while `Application requires iPhone environment` will appear in both. I have no idea how Xcode determines this.</sup>

---

### Want `Info.plist` back, completely?

You might want all of your app's properties in one place. Or maybe you don't trust Xcode with the merging. I spoke with an Apple engineer at WWDC21 about this... here's how to get the classic `Info.plist` back.

1. Create a new "Property List" file (<kbd>File</kbd> -> <kbd>New</kbd> -> <kbd>File</kbd>)

[image: Property List option selected in new file popup]

2. Name it `Info.plist`

[image: File will be saved in the same file hierarchy level as ContentView.swift]

3. Copy and paste the existing values from `Project -> Targets -> Info -> Custom iOS Target Properties` to `Info.plist`.

| Copy | Paste |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Individual row inside Custom iOS Target Properties selected] | [image: Row pasted into Info.plist] |

*Note: Currently you can only select and copy 1 row at a time. If you want to save some time, here are the [default contents](https://gist.github.com/aheze/fe11e259f78c4716897a599e01e593e2) in XML format. To use this, right-click* `Info.plist` -> <kbd>Open As</kbd> -> <kbd>Source Code</kbd>*, then paste.*

4. Copy the path to `Info.plist` in the attributes inspector.

[image: Full path selected]

5. Paste the path here:

```
Project -> Targets -> Build Settings -> Info.plist File
```

[image: Full path pasted]

6. Set `Generate Info.plist File` to **No**

[image: Yes or No popup after selecting row]

7. Last step. Remove `Info.plist` from `Copy Bundle Resources` (select, then press the <kbd>-</kbd> button).

```
Project -> Targets -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources
```

[image: Info.plist selected in Copy Bundle Resources]

Yep, that was a lot. But whether you want classic `Info.plist` or not is up to you — both are fine and won't change your app.

Comment: You probably mean minus button, not plus button.

Comment: it makes absolutely no sense! The first time you add/edit, Xcode will automatically generate a new Info.plist file that’s kind of synced1 with Custom iOS Target Properties. Xcode will later merge them for you.

Comment: I've edited it and still no plist file!! What a mess Apple and Xcode has become in recent years!!

Comment: Beware - don't use absolute path for an Info.plist file, relative from project root is ok and won't break when building on another computer.

Comment: Uhm, so in this new "plist". How do I add a new property? I don't see a plus on top

EDIT: Got it. Press the plus on for instance the "Bundle name" and it works

Comment: In Xcode 13.2.1 the Info.plist file already exists in the main target so I followed the steps from #6, although you still need to create those for test targets and remember not to assign target membership to the Info.plist

Comment: a demonstration of finding the info tab:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mml9ZI81VKA

Comment: My god, why must Apple take tried and true files and processes that we are used to and change them for no benefit whatsoever?

Comment: the broken link to release notes : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-13-release-notes

Comment: I just want to add `NSCameraUsageDescription` and don't see which `+` I need to do it

Comment: @WilliamEntriken Right-click and click "Raw keys and values"

Answer (score 29):

It's a little tricky to discover how to add/edit values (using Xcode 14):

1. Select your Target from the side panel
2. Select the **Info** tab
3. **Hover over any item** in the list to reveal the +/- buttons
4. Click **+** button
5. Select something from the options (it's a really long list)

*[Update: adding an entry this way will ALSO create a plist file. It will simply be empty.]*

[image]

Comment: I'm surprised this simple solution didn't get the most votes. It creates the Info.plist file automatically and everything!

Comment: This is the simplest and correct answer

Comment: It seems that the new file is only created when you add a key that is not one of Apple's defaults. I had a set of values in from text that I was pasting in, and I had to add a dummy value to the list first to create the new file and then delete the dummy value in the new file to paste in my values as a source code editor.

Answer (score 3):

Xcode 13.3.1, macOS Monterey(12.0.1)

Here is the most simple solution which work for both swiftUI and Storyboard projects, if you are not able to find info.plist and want to add target properties like *Privacy - Camera Usage Description* and things like we can add in older Xcode version. Here is the solution...

---

```
***> Select target of you project on top of the files click on Info on
> top of the right side, now you can see "Custom iOS properties" like
> info.plist, do whatever you want.***
```

---

**Target > Info**

see the image below for reference

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This also applies to Xcode 14. To be brief, a few pieces of information about this change:

1. There is a good write up of the issue here:
   https://useyourloaf.com/blog/xcode-13-missing-info.plist/
2. There is a good YouTube video (found in this page above):
   https://youtu.be/mml9ZI81VKA
3. This issue applies to SwiftUI projects not Storyboard. Once you make
   a change to the "standard" info settings, Xcode actually
   automatically creates an info.plist file in your project navigator. You can then add more custom settings in the info.plist file.

Comment: I appreciate you pointing out item #3!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a raywenderlich tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/19611194-multiplatform-app-tutorial-swiftui-and-xcode-12

The sample projects uses `Xcode 12.0-compatible` (objectVersion = 54) project format, created with the `Multi Platform` app template. I borrowed the plists from this project. Until the sample project is revised, it's nice to have a reference project (structure) for comparison.