# Adding custom font to Xcode 13+

Tags: swift, xcode13

Now that Apple has taken away the Plist, naturally it has changed the way we add custom fonts to our app. Before we just added the file to our bundle and set a property for it and our plist and viola..

Now I am curious.. can it be done without adding a custom plist as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67896404/where-is-info-plist-in-xcode-13-missing-not-inside-project-navigator) or is that the only option?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. drag and drop your font-file into the project (make sure you hit copy if needed and check the target box)

[image: drag&drop]

2. choose Project -> Targets -> Info -> Custom iOS Target Properties and klick the small + icon under the "key" property. Start typing "*Fonts provided by application*"

[image]

3. enter the full font-filename inside this property-list

[image]

4. now you can use the font by its name
5. (Bonus: if you have trouble to find the font name, you can print all available fonts with [see detail explanation for this at [code with chris](https://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/) ]:

```html
 for family: String in UIFont.familyNames
        {
            print(family)
            for names: String in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family)
            {
                print("== \(names)")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add font files name same as you add in project directory `info.plist`

Just go to

```
Project -> Targets -> Info -> Custom iOS Target Properties
```

Add your all permission or file here.

[image]

Comment: I don't think that's what he or she is talking about if you read the forwarding topic.

Answer (score 0):

Also when using the font in swiftui you need to remove the .ttf

so Silkscreen-Regular.ttf is Silkscreen-Regular

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
//run this init to get a list of all of the fonts you project can see
 init() {
    for familyName in UIFont.familyNames {
        print(familyName)
        for fontName in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: familyName){
            print("--\(fontName)")
        }
    }
   }
  }
```