# Unable to add custom fonts to Xcode 14.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm unable to get any custom fonts working based on the [instructions in Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app) and stack overflow answers. Here is my setup that I would expect to work:

**1) When copying font files into project:**

[image]

**2) Font .ttf files are added to project**

[image]

**3) Target membership is selected**

[image]

**4) Font names added to UIAppFonts in `info.plist`**

```
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <String>SourceSerifPro-Black.ttf</String>
        <String>SourceSerifPro-BlackItalic.ttf</String>
        <String>SourceSerifPro-Bold.ttf</String>
        <String>SourceSerifPro-BoldItalic.ttf</String>
        <String>SourceSerifPro-ExtraLight.ttf</String>
        <String>SourceSerifPro-ExtraLightItalic.ttf</String>
        <String>SourceSerifPro-Italic.ttf</String>
        <String>SourceSerifPro-Light.ttf</String>
        <String>SourceSerifPro-LightItalic.ttf</String>
        <String>SourceSerifPro-Regular.ttf</String>
        <String>SourceSerifPro-SemiBold.ttf</String>
        <String>SourceSerifPro-SemiBoldItalic.ttf</String>
    </array>
```

**5) Fonts are present under Copy Bundle Resources**

[image]

**6) All system fonts are logged, but new fonts are not found**

```
for family in UIFont.familyNames.sorted() {
    let names = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family)
    print("Family: \(family) Font names: \(names)")
}
```

**7) Tried using the font but only seeing the default font**

```
Text("Test text")
  .font(.custom("SourceSerifPro-Regular", size: 20))
```

I've also erased and restarted the simulator and restart my computer and Xcode multiple times. Any idea what else I may be missing?

Comment: It indeed looks okay. Thing I'd also try is clearing the build folder and deleting derived data.

Comment: what's the key that you are using in the .plist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had ran into similar problem. Try calling this function once before using any custom font.

```
private func registerCustomFonts() {
    let fonts = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "ttf", subdirectory: nil)
    fonts?.forEach { url in
        CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL(url as CFURL, .process, nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do we need to add this? Although it works, but it doesn't justify why we can't use normally

Comment: Yeah it sucks. We can however use custom fonts directly in xib or storyboard without above code block. Only guess I have is that iOS doesn't registers programmatic fonts automatically to save on app startup time.

Answer (score 0):

[Adding custom font to Xcode 13+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68056195/adding-custom-font-to-xcode-13)

Do take note. I made the mistake not adding the extension.ttf so it didn't import. But otherwise it should.