# Opting out of Dark Mode with iOS 15 using Xcode 13

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm attempting to opt my app out of dark mode as I'm not supporting dark mode yet. Following various threads I've been unable to figure out how to do this with Xcode 13.

Originally I followed [Is it possible to opt-out of dark mode on iOS 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537855/is-it-possible-to-opt-out-of-dark-mode-on-ios-13), but seems like plist was removed in Xcode 13 [Where is Info.plist in Xcode 13? (missing, not inside project navigator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67896404/where-is-info-plist-in-xcode-13-missing-not-inside-project-navigator).

How do you opt out of dark mode with the plist now being removed in Xcode 13? Or please do correct me if I am wrong.

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to opt-out of dark mode on iOS 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537855/is-it-possible-to-opt-out-of-dark-mode-on-ios-13)

Comment: It does partially, but I couldn't figure out how to turn it off globally @Turtleeeeee

Comment: Did you try the Xcode 13 part? Info.plist values are moved to build settings. Go to build settings and search for info.plist then you could find UIUserInterfaceStyle and set it to light.

Comment: What UI framework are you using on development? UIKit or SwiftUI?

Comment: I will try this and loop back today, I am using SwiftUI!

Comment: So I'm attempting to follow this but cannot figure out how to edit the Info.plist keys/values in Xcode https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/appearance_customization/supporting_dark_mode_in_your_interface/choosing_a_specific_interface_style_for_your_ios_app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone else who lands here using Xcode 13. Here are the steps

1. First, click on your project.

[image]

2. Click on "Info"

[image]

3. Click on the "+" on any Key to open a new K,V pair and add "Apperance" -> set value to "Light"

[image]

4. Double check it exists in "Build Settings" under Info.plist Values under "User Interface Style" -> Light

[image]

Comment: Your images are very small and the text on them is hard to read. Consider using both large images *and* adding some text-based guidance to help navigate the UI.

Comment: I don't think I have enough reputation to edit, I was going to enlarge the images and add text :[

Comment: You can edit your own post at any reputation level. Do you see an "Edit" link under the answer?

Comment: Oh, wow I need new glasses I didn't see that. Hah, I'll edit it now