# Xcode: How to add key into generated Info.plist file (or merge generated and existing Info.plist)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have been using `Info.plist` in my projects, but recently I noticed that freshly generated new projects don't contain them anymore, and `Info.plist` is instead generated by Xcode at build time, from `Info.plist Values` section in target's `Build settings`.

I like this, as it would allow me to ship two projects (beta and non-beta one) from a same folder, without special build steps modifying the Info.plist for each project.

However, I noticed that:

1. Many Info.plist keys are missing in Build settings (eg. ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption, or NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription/NSLocationUsageDescription/NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription), so I cannot set them from there. There also doesn't appear to be any `+` sign when hovering, which would let me add another key into that section.
2. And the way of adding `INFOPLIST_KEY_ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption = NO;` into a `.pbxproj` file, which I have found documented somewhere, no longer works.

Is there a way of adding additional keys into generated `Info.plist`? Or, is there a way of having both both `Info.plist` file in a filesystem, and `Info.plist Values` section in build settings, and make Xcode merge them during build?

Here is how the section looks like:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67896404/where-is-info-plist-in-xcode-13-missing-not-inside-project-navigator

Comment: Since you didn't tag this [swiftui], I'll assume it's UIKit. Just created (in Xcode 13.1) two new projects - and yes, if it's SwiftUI you no longer have an info.plist file in the Project Explorer. BUT - if you create a "Storyboard" project (which is actually a UIKit project) you do get one.

Answer (score 1):

So, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67896404/where-is-info-plist-in-xcode-13-missing-not-inside-project-navigator) was helpful (thank you [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5508175/andrew)!), but the core insight I got from experimenting is:

1. Xcode doesn't want to let you enter invalid keys in places they don't belong.
2. Build Settings only have basic properties, anything else belongs into the 'Info' section. Editing it will create a new `Info.plist file` with only the changed properties, which will then be merged with info.plist keys from build settings (I couldn't find a documentation for build order).
3. Some settings, like `ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption` for standalone watch-only apps have no place to go.
   Apple mostly abandoned standalone watchapps, there is a ton of bugs around them and they don't care.