How can I view the app's plist file as source code in Xcode?
When I change or add something to my app's plist, a minimal plist appears on the left side of Xcode. I can open this small plist as source code. My question is: how can I view the base or entire app plist located in the Info tab under the "Custom macOS Application Target Properties" section as source code?


Why do you want it to show the source code under the "Info" tab? Why not just open the Info.plist file as source code?

I want open Info.plist as source code, but I cannot that is why I am asking for help, in the question I mentioned I can open the samll plist on the left side in Xcode, but the big plist file like in the photo I do not know where it is located and how to open it as a source code.

What's the "small" plist and the "big" plist? There should be only one Info.plist.

Check the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67896404/where-is-info-plist-in-xcode-13-missing-not-inside-project-navigator

@Sweeper: Look at the photo in question, I update.

Aren't they are the same thing?

No, they are not the same. The one in the Info tag contains additional information, while the one on the left only has the edited content we modify. Also, I have to close and reopen Xcode multiple times for the plist in the Info tag to synchronize with the smaller plist on the left side. It's a bit bothersome to ensure that my app's plist is properly synced between the two different plist files.

Overview
The display in the "Info" tab is an amalgamation of the Info.plist and project information stored in project.pbxproj
To view the Info.plist as source
From the "Project Navigator", the file viewer will show .plist files with a specific icon for the file type (as your images show in the question).
Xcode also provides different secondary-menu choices, using "Open As" including:

"Source Code"
"Quick Look"

Both of those will give you different-styled text-only view of the plist, which is ultimately an XML-style file.
To view the project's stored values
Take the label of the value in the UI, and look for it in the Build settings reference
For example, if you want to look at "Launch Screen Interface File Base Name"

Launch Screen Interface File Base Name
Setting name: INFOPLIST_KEY_UILaunchStoryboardName
When GENERATE_INFOPLIST_FILE is enabled, sets the value of the UILaunchStoryboardName key in the Info.plist file to the value of this build setting.

So, go into project.pbxproj
and look for INFOPLIST_KEY_UILaunchStoryboardName
These values are set on a per-target basis, so in a normal project, you might see as many as three entires (one in Info.plist and two in project.pbxproj (one for "debug" and one for "release")).
BONUS:
If you just want to get the literal name of tag in the file, from the normal display you can secondary click-and-hold to pull up a menu and turn on "Raw Keys and Values". This is often faster when you are just researching the contents of a mysterious Info.plist

If you read my question I already mentioned your answer in my question even in photo. Your answer simply does not answer my question, also give some other information that I not asked for, but thanks for your help.

That's the closest you are going to get to "the base or entire app plist located in the Info tab under the "Custom macOS Application Target Properties" section as source code... The other stuff is and buried in the xml of the project.
Give me a specific value you want to understand in your UI, and I'll append this answer.

okay, I was "waiting for a turkey", so I added some more details.
