Xcode Build Error: "Build input file cannot be found" for Info.plist After Migrating from UIKit to SwiftUI
I'm encountering a persistent build error in my Xcode project after attempting to migrate my app from UIKit to SwiftUI. Despite several troubleshooting steps, the issue remains unresolved. Below are the details of the problem, the error message, and the steps I've taken so far to try to fix it.
### Error Message:
Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/rgf10hotmail.es/Desktop/Developer/Recipeas2024/CocinArtGit/Recipeas/Info.plist'. Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it?

### Project Context:

Migration: Transitioning the app from UIKit to SwiftUI.

Xcode Version: Latest version (as of 2024-12-03).

SwiftUI Setup: Removed AppDelegate and SceneDelegate as part of the migration.

Info.plist: Created a new Info.plist file at Recipeas/Info.plist.


Steps Taken to Resolve the Issue:

Verified Info.plist Path in Project Settings:

Checked under Build Settings → Packaging → Info.plist File.

Updated the path to the new Info.plist location (Recipeas/Info.plist).



Checked Build Phases:

Reviewed Build Phases → Copy Bundle Resources to ensure Info.plist is included.

Verified that no custom build scripts reference the old Info.plist path.



Cleaned Build Folder and Deleted Derived Data:

Performed Product > Clean Build Folder.

Deleted Derived Data manually from ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData.



Removed Obsolete References:

Ensured there are no references to the old Info.plist path in the project navigator.

Removed any red-highlighted file references indicating missing files.



Updated Project File Directly:

Opened project.pbxproj to search for any lingering references to the old Info.plist path.

Made necessary corrections, ensuring no absolute paths are pointing to the deleted location.



Verified Search Paths:

Checked Build Settings for Header Search Paths, Library Search Paths, and Framework Search Paths to ensure they do not reference the old path.


Re-added Info.plist to Project:

Removed the current Info.plist reference and re-added it to ensure Xcode recognizes the new file correctly.


Rebooted Xcode and System:

Restarted Xcode multiple times.

Restarted my Mac to ensure all caches are cleared.



Checked Multiple Targets:

Verified that all targets in the project reference the correct Info.plist.


Ensured Relative Paths:

Confirmed that the project uses relative paths instead of absolute paths to avoid path resolution issues.



### Additional Notes:

The error message references a path that has been deleted: /Users/rgf10hotmail.es/Desktop/Developer/Recipeas2024/CocinArtGit/Recipeas/Info.plist.

I have ensured that no scripts or build rules are attempting to access this old path.

The project was functioning correctly before the migration from UIKit to SwiftUI.


### What I've Tried So Far:

Cleaning the build folder and deleting Derived Data.

Updating the Info.plist path in project settings.

Removing and re-adding the Info.plist file to the project.

Searching the entire project for any references to the old Info.plist path.

Ensuring all build phases and scripts are updated to use the new Info.plist path.

Restarting Xcode and my computer.


Despite these efforts, the build process still fails with the same error. I'm unsure where the build system is still referencing the old Info.plist path.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <!-- Google Mobile Ads SDK -->
    <key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
    <string>ca-app-pub-9021089007171782~8539445706</string>
    
    <!-- App Transport Security -->
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    
    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>Montserrat-Black.ttf</string>
        <string>Montserrat-Bold.ttf</string>
        <string>Montserrat-ExtraBold.otf</string>
        <string>Montserrat-ExtraLight.ttf</string>
        <string>Montserrat-Light.ttf</string>
        <string>Montserrat-Medium.ttf</string>
        <string>Montserrat-Regular.ttf</string>
    </array>
    
    <!-- User Interface Style -->
    <key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
    <string>Light</string>
</dict>
</plist>





import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            HomeView()
                .navigationTitle("Recipeas")
        }
    }
}


import SwiftUI
import GoogleMobileAds

@main
struct NameApp: App {
    // Initialize Google Mobile Ads SDK
    init() {
        GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}


Info.plist is not visible as a separate file until you add non-standard values to it

Do you see the Info.plist in your project?
Do you see the values of it reflected under [Blue Project Icon in Project Navigator] -> Targets -> [Your Target Name] -> Info?
Did you try to add a custom value to it? (this will trigger it to become visible)

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67896587/2804585
