# how to use custom system fonts in swiftui

Tags: swiftui

in swiftui,
how can i use the systems fonts?

code::

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
       
            Text("This is a text")
                      .font(.custom("IowanOldStyle-Roman", size: 28))
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

the code above is not working.

i found this post from apple but it didnt work::
https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/659219

i found this stackoverflow but it didnt work::
[SwiftUI won't display custom font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58864731/swiftui-wont-display-custom-font)

this is what my info.plist looks like:::

[image]

Comment: It's pretty telling that in that screen shot the font file never appears. Drag it into your project (right into the project navigator on the left side of that screen shot). Without the font file, everything else you're doing is just empty words.

Comment: What are custom system fonts?  Custom fonts?  Or installing and using custom fonts in the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the font (.ttf file) to your project folder too. Double check at

> Project -> Targets -> Build phases -> Copy Bundle Resources

[image]